# A question about sets _ empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A , B$ be sets.
>
> Prove that $B= \emptyset$ if and only if $(B \cap A') \cup (A \cap B') = A $.

I know how to prove it from $B= \emptyset$ to $(B \cap A') \cup (A \cap B') = A $. But I don't know how to prove from $(B \cap A') \cup (A \cap B') = A $ to $B= \emptyset$. I think it can be solved by considering different states. Such $A = B$ , $A \cap B = \emptyset$ , $A \cap B = C \neq \emptyset$. But I want to know whether there is a solution without considering different states or not. (I mean a more direct proof without examining different states that may happen)

Note:
$A'$ is complement of $A$

Comment: Is $A'$ a notation for the complement of $A$?

Comment: @Wore yes it is complement of A.

Comment: Did you read the description of the tag you used? Please use `elementary-set-theory` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that $(B\cap A')\cup (A\cap B')=A$ implies $B=\emptyset$ as follows:

Suppose $B\neq \emptyset$. Then there is an element $x\in B$, and we have two cases:

- If $x\not\in A$, then $x\in B\cap A'\subseteq (B\cap A')\cup (A\cap B')=A$, a contradiction.
- If $x\in A=(B\cap A')\cup (A\cap B')$, then $x\in (B\cap A')$ or $x\in (B\cap A')$, but this last two options are impossible as $x$ belongs to both $B$ and $A$.

Thus, there is no element $x\in B$, and so $B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

If $B=\emptyset$, then $(B\cap \bar A)\cup (A\cap \bar B)= A\cap G= A$, where $G$ denotes the universal set.
Conversely, let $x\in B$. If $x\in \bar A$, then $x\in B\cap \bar A$ and so $x\in (B\cap \bar A)\cup(A\cap\bar B)$ but $x\not\in A$.
If $x\in A$, then $x\not\in \bar A$ and so $x\not\in(B\cap\bar A)\cup(A\cap\bar B)$ but $x\in A$. So in both cases, the quality of sets cannot hold.